# Pipe result from subprocess to unix sort

Tags: python, subprocess, piping

I am calling a perl script on an external txt files from python, and printing the output to an outfile. But instead I want to pipe the output to unix's sort. Right now I am not piping, but are writing the output from the perl program first, then doing by combining my code under, and [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409939/2169327).

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

for file in os.listdir("."):

    with open(file + ".out", 'w') as outfile:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "pydyn.pl", file], stdout=outfile)
        p.wait()
```

Comment: You are using python incorrectly. If you are going to be calling a lot of outside processes (like sort), instead of using python modules, it's better to use bash, ipython or other shell.

Comment: you can also pipe the result 
`p = subprocess.Popen("perl pydyn.pl %s | sort" % file, stdout=outfile,shell=True)` but for this you're gonna have to make it `shell=True` which is not a good practice

Comment: related: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked the question in python you can also pipe the result

```
p = subprocess.Popen("perl pydyn.pl %s | sort" % file, stdout=outfile,shell=True)
```

but for this you're gonna have to make it `shell=True` which is not a good practice

Here's one way without making it `shell=True`

```
  p = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "pydyn.pl", file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  output = subprocess.check_output(['sort'], stdin=p.stdout,stdout=outfile)
  p.wait()
```

Comment: `check_output` is incorrect here; you can't change `stdout`. `"%s" % file` breaks if `file` contains space or `$`, etc e.g., it allows to execute arbitrary commands. You shoulld close `p.stdout` for proper cleanup. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29021053/4279)

Answer (score 4):

To emulate the shell pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pipes
import subprocess

pipeline = "perl pydyn.pl {f} | sort >{f}.out".format(f=pipes.quote(filename))
subprocess.check_call(pipeline, shell=True)
```

without invoking the shell in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

perl = Popen(['perl', 'pydyn.pl', filename], stdout=PIPE)
with perl.stdout, open(filename+'.out', 'wb', 0) as outfile:
    sort = Popen(['sort'], stdin=perl.stdout, stdout=outfile)
perl.wait() # wait for perl to finish
rc = sort.wait() # wait for `sort`, get exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use bash. Using python just adds a level of complexity you don't need.

```
for file in $( ls); 
do 
    perl pydyn.pl $file | sort
done
```

Above is a quick and dirty example, a better alternative in terms of parsing is the following:

```
ls | while read file; do perl pydyn.pl "$file" | sort; done
```

Comment: it fails on the first file that has space in the name

Comment: This could be due to a number of reasons. I added another example that will probably solve the issue.

Comment: it is incorrect. It should be `read file`, not `read $file`. `bash` skips over such errors *silently*. [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *"Errors should never pass silently.  Unless explicitly silenced."*